# Linq to XML 'Where not in' syntax problem

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml, linq-to-objects

The following Code does not compile

```
Dim BasicGroups As String() = New String() {"Node1", "Node2"}
Dim NodesToRemove = From Element In SchemaDoc.Root.<Group> _
                    Where Element.@Name not in BasicGroups
For Each XNode In NodesToRemove
    XNode.Remove()
Next
```

It is supposed to Remove any Immediate child of the rootnode which has an attribute called name whose value is **Not** listed in the BasicGroups StringArray.

**What is the correct syntax for this task?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to move the 'not' part. Eg (psuedo code)

```
where (not (list.Contains(foo))
```

Comment: So in my case .....Where Not BasicGroups.Contains(Element.@Name)... Which works Great.. Thanks.

Comment: Good, I wasnt sure about the VB syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

If the Name attribute of the nodes to be removed can be matched using a simple pattern, the following should work:

```
Dim SchemaDoc As New XDocument(<Root><Group Name="Foo"/><Group Name="Node1"/>
                           <Group Name="Node2"/><Group name="Bar"/></Root>)
Dim NodesToRemove = From Element In SchemaDoc.<Root>.<Group> Where _
                           Element.@Name Like "NotNode?"
For Each XNode In NodesToRemove.ToArray()
  XNode.Remove()
Next
```

Do note the use of ToArray() in the enumeration of NodesToRemove: you'll need this to force evaluation of the XQuery prior to starting to modify the collection it's based on.

If this won't work, here's an alternative to using LINQ (as originally I thought that inserting 'not' into LINQ queries wouldn't work, but I was set straight by another answer -- you learn something new every day...):

```
Dim NodesToRemove As New Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of XNode)
For Each Element In SchemaDoc.<Root>.<Group>
  If Not BasicGroups.Contains(Element.@Name) Then
    NodesToRemove.Add(Element)
  End If
Next
```

Performance should be pretty much identical to using LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this

mylistWithOutUndesirebleNodes = 
(from b in NodeLists.Cast()
   where (from c in NodesToDeleteList.Cast()
          where c.Attributes["atributo"].Value == b.Attributes["atributo"].Value
          select c).Count() == 0
 select b).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim NodesToRemove = From Element In SchemaDoc.Root.<Group> _
                    Where Not BasicGroups.Contains(Element.@Name)
```